# Is there a way to remove a vertical bright stripe in an image in OpenCv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv

I have a an image as below:[image]

In this image there two bright lines that run through the image, these are what i want to remove/reduce the appearance of.

I have used a threshold to be able to identify these bright stripes, which picks out the areas quite well:

[image]

Currently im trying a reduce method where im trying to just reduce the bightness of the pixels so they dont stand out as much in the image. However, this is leading to odd looking results, to which im not sure why this is the case.

The odd looking results:
[image]

From what i can see it is changing the values of the pixels but its leaving odd results in the final image.

I have been using this code so far to carry out the process:

```
img = cv2.imread('43.bmp')

h,s,v= cv2.split(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV))

ret1,th1 = cv2.threshold(v,240,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

bright = np.where(th1, np.where((255-v) < 40, v-30,v),0)

th1_n = cv2.bitwise_not(th1) 
dark = np.where(th1_n,v,0)

result = bright + dark

mergeColour = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.merge([h,s,result]),cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

cv2.imshow("frame", mergeColour.astype(np.uint8))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Im not sure exactly where im going wrong or if there is a possibilty of a better method of getting what id like

Edit:

*** What id like to see is that visable lines become a similar birghtness to the others around it, so it would appear that they have been removed from the image ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the assumption that the bright spots appear always as vertical lines. It is tested on this sample image and the results are quite good, but it would certanly need more testing on other similar pictures. That being said, I would recomend you try to locate the white spots on the thresholded image that are this 'spots', just like you already posted in the second last image. You can get the locations or coordinates if you prefer by transposing the function `np.findnonzero(thresholded_image)`. Then iterate through the list and replace all pixels of the original image with the same coordinate as the iter with the pixel before that one (x-1). This is the result:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('remove.png')
height,width = img.shape[:2]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,225,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cds = np.transpose(np.nonzero(thresh))
for i in cds:
    if i[1] == 0:
        pass
    else:
        img[i[0],i[1]] = img[i[0], i[1]-1]


cv2.imshow("res", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Original image:

[image]

Thersholded image:

[image]

Result image:

[image]

Hope it helps a bit or give you a new idea that could be useful. Cheers!

EDIT:

Or one even better approach:
Use the `cv2.inpaint()` function instead of iterating through every pixel:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('remove.png')
mask = cv2.imread('thresh.png',0)

dst = cv2.inpaint(img,mask,3,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)

cv2.imshow('dst',dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what output you hope for, but one method to remove uneven lighting is to take a copy of the image and blur it over a large area to remove high frequency changes and retain only low frequency, slowly changing areas and call that the background lighting. Then subtract this background from the original image.

I just do it with ImageMagick which is included on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. So, just in Terminal:

```
convert input.gif \( +clone -blur 0x32 \) -compose difference -composite -auto-level result.jpg
```

[image]

You can do exactly the same in Python or C++ with OpenCV, or PIL/Pillow or with CImg or with ImageMagick Python bindings.

In essence, the processing removes the following as background lighting:

[image]